# Entity Framework Returns NULL linked object C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework in my program, and I have a problem when a record is being removable from the table, the table linked objects come NULL.

Instead of doing

```
waitTravel = db.WaitTravels 
               .Where(w => w.suggestTravelId == suggestTravelId &&
                           w.wantedTravelId == wantedTravelId)
               .First();

if (waitTravel.WantedTravels.statusTravelId != 1)
```

I should do that:

```
 if (db.WantedTravels.Where(w => w.id == waitTravel.wantedTravelId).First().statusTravelId != 1)
```

Know something to help me?

Comment: Do you mean why is waitTravel.WantedTravels null in your if condition?

Comment: yes, thanks for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is why is `waitTravel.WantedTravels` null in your `if` statement. That is because you are missing an `include` statement and you do not have lazy loading enabled.

See the EF documentation on [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for additional options on how you can accomplish this. The easiest, and IMO best way, is to explicitly use `Include` when you know you want to retrieve a related property/collection.

```
waitTravel = db.WaitTravels 
               .Where(w => w.suggestTravelId == suggestTravelId &&
                           w.wantedTravelId == wantedTravelId)
               .Include(w => w.WantedTravels) // added
               .First();
```

---

If this is not what you are asking then please clarify your question.

Comment: There is a way to do this in a general way the entire program?

Comment: @R.H - You can enable lazy loading for the entire `DbContext`. See [How to: Use Lazy Loading to Load Related Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx)